# Self-Avoiding Walk using backtracking recursion

Tags: c, recursion, backtracking

Given : grid m×n
I'm require to enumerate all path that have no more than one intersection and that ends at the upper right corner using backtracking and recursion !? any suggestions .? 

 
[Self-Avoiding Walk](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Self-AvoidingWalk.html)

Comment: What have you done/tried so far?

Comment: The obvious starting point would be a flood-fill style algorithm. Pick a starting square (if one isn't specified) and mark it as having been used, then recursively try all its neighbors that aren't marked as used.

Comment: Look up **maze solving** algorithms.  The only difference is in how the question of "can I move forward in this direction or not" is answered.

Comment: PS: If you do find code somewhere that makes it **click** for you, please add a comment to your code referencing where you learned what you needed.  It is a _Good Habit_ to get in to.

Comment: I'll put my own code when I finish .

Answer (score 3):

The non-recursive way is to keep a stack of previous positions and the information requiring a decision at that position.  Each time a decision is made, push the information you need to save on the top of the stack.

Then when your search forward find a problem, it pop the stack and jump back to the most recent decision point and make a different decision.  Eventually you either succeed, or eliminate all possible paths as impossible.

For a recursive solution, it is the same, except instead of pushing information onto a stack, you pass the new position after a decision in the recursive call.  If the recursive call returns failure, you try the next possible decision at the current position.  If you run out of choices at the current position, return failure to the level above.  Only if the recursive call returns success does this level return success.

Again, eventually a success is returned up the entire call chain, or all possible paths are eliminated.

And since this is homework, you have to decide for yourself what information needs to be passed from one level to the next, and how your final success path is returned to the application.

All the new ideas you need are in the paragraphs above.  The implementation remains up to you.

-Jesse

Comment: +1 Good answer for a homework question.